# Locker Service and CSS in JS

Tags: javascript, css, locker-service, react

Without trying this myself I was curious if anyone else was able to get CSS in JS to work within the confines of LockerService. At first glance it looks like styled-components might actually work as it seems to meet at the standards demanded by LockerService, but I was hoping someone could quickly confirm/deny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to manipulate both style and style classes in JavaScript. Obviously, you can't manipulate styles outside of components outside of your own namespace, but everything else is fair game.

Comment: Excellent, I'll give this a shot then.